# HTML JS Accordion to collapse the remaining and alert the active

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code where I need atleast one section at a time and not to allow 2 or more sections to be opened. When the click the button "Show Active accordion number"  it should alert with the section number

Can anyone help me out with this?

that is to behave like https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<h2>Accordion with symbols</h2>
<p>In this example we have added a "plus" sign to each button. When the user clicks on the button, the "plus" sign is replaced with a "minus" sign.</p>
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button onclick="alert('active acoordion is:')">Show Active accordion number</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    var label = this.innerHTML;
    var currentClasses = this.classList.toString();
    
    for (j = 0; j < acc.length; j++) {
      if(acc[j]!=this)
          acc[j].classList = "accordion";
          acc[j].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
    }
    
    //if(currentClasses.includes('active')) 
    
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}

var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("show-current")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    var classes = acc[i].classList.toString();
    if (classes.includes('active'))
        alert( acc[i].innerHTML )
    }
  }
```

```css
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button class="show-current">show current section</button>

<h2>Accordion with symbols</h2>
<p>In this example we have added a "plus" sign to each button. When the user clicks on the button, the "plus" sign is replaced with a "minus" sign.</p>
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    
    for (var j= 0; j< acc.length; j++){
      acc[j].classList.remove('active');
      acc[j].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
        
    }
    
    this.classList.add("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}

function showActive(){
   for (var j= 0; j< acc.length; j++){
     
        if(acc[j].className.indexOf('active') != -1){
          alert(acc[j].innerHTML);
        }
    }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<h2>Accordion with symbols</h2>
<p>In this example we have added a "plus" sign to each button. When the user clicks on the button, the "plus" sign is replaced with a "minus" sign.</p>
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button onclick="showActive()">Show Active accordion number</button>
```

Comment: In this solution, the onclick on the same tab multiple times, does not change the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. The below code will expand only one accordion at any point of time. Also, the code will toggle single accordion (i.e. click on section 1, it expands and again click on section 1, it closes).

```js
window.onload = function () {
 var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
 var i;

 for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function (e) {

   [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".accordion")).map(function (el) {
    if (el.innerHTML != e.target.innerHTML) {
     el.classList.remove("active");
     el.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null
    }
   })

   this.classList.toggle("active");
   var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
   if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
    panel.style.maxHeight = null;
   } else {
    panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
   }
  }
 }
}

function showNo() {
 if (document.querySelector("button.accordion.active") != null)
  alert(document.querySelector("button.accordion.active").innerHTML.replace("Section ", ""))
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
 background-color: #eee;
 color: #444;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 18px;
 width: 100%;
 border: none;
 text-align: left;
 outline: none;
 font-size: 15px;
 transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
 background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
 content: '\002B';
 color: #777;
 font-weight: bold;
 float: right;
 margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
 content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
 padding: 0 18px;
 background-color: white;
 max-height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<h2>Accordion with symbols</h2>
<p>In this example we have added a "plus" sign to each button. When the user clicks on the button, the "plus" sign is replaced
 with a "minus" sign.</p>
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
  aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
  aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
  aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button id="showNo" onclick="showNo()">Show Active accordion number</button>
```

Comment: This should not allow 2 or more to be open. How can we achive this. When 1 section is clicked it shoulkd close the remiaing open sections

Comment: @CodeGuy I have updated my code. Updated code will expand only one accordion at any point of time. Also, my code will toggle single accordion (i.e. you click on section 1, it expands and again click on section 1, it closes)

Answer (score 0):

Just close all panels in a loop and open the current one after.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

function closePanels() {
  var panelElements = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");
  
  for (i = 0; i < panelElements.length; i++) {
    panelElements[i].style.maxHeight = 0;
 }
}



for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    // close all panels
    closePanels();
    
    // open current panel
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<h2>Accordion with symbols</h2>
<p>In this example we have added a "plus" sign to each button. When the user clicks on the button, the "plus" sign is replaced with a "minus" sign.</p>
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```